# Render github fork button

Tags: requirejs, commonjs

I want to render "reload" github buttons correctly, when i press on another button. I searched and i got [this information](https://github.com/ntkme/github-buttons#advanced-usage), but I can't do it, i faced another error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "github-buttons" has not been loaded yet
>   for context: _. Use require([]).

when i include http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js

Comment: what framework/lib you're using? ie: angular, react or vue?

Comment: pure javascript, but i included require.js lately and doesn't work. @Microsmsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Node.JS is a server-side technology, not a browser technology. Thus,
>   Node-specific calls, like require(), do not work in the browser.
>
> See [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) if you wish to serve browser-specific
>   modules from Node.

But you can use their steps in order to make this button...

**[Usage:](https://buttons.github.io/)**

> 1. Place this tag where you want the button to render

```
<a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/microsmsm" data-
size="large" aria-label="Follow @microsmsm on GitHub">Follow 
@microsmsm</a>
```

> 2. Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag

```
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
```

**Code Example**:

https://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/NvJaNm?editors=1100

**Reference**:

https://buttons.github.io/

Comment: Ok. Make a button that creates this github button in every time you click on it, and you got the error!

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/zeyadetman/pen/ZJPXxB when you press 'click' button fork button doesn't appear in style and appear just an a element. @Microsmsm

Comment: I don't recommend using this lib to do so ... it's manipulating HTML so you can't really re-render the button using this techinique

Comment: I used this technique and works with me `(function() {
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.src = (/^http:/.test(document.location) ? "http" : "https") + "://buttons.github.io/buttons.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
    })();` Thanks @Microsmsm